# How to find and unzip all the .zip archives in a directory with Python?

Tags: python, zip, unzip

I wish to scan a directory with Python make a list with the names of all the `.zip` archives in the directory and then extract those `zip` archives to a different directory.

For example I have a `downloads` directory and a `unpacked` directory. The `downloads` directory contains a `data_002.zip` and `measurements-033.zip` archive and other folders and files. Whats the best way to extract both of these archives in the `unpacked` directory?

I  scan all the contents of the `downloads` directory looking for a `.zip` ending and then extract them like :

```
import os
from os import path
from pathlib import Path

archives = []
for content in os.listdir("downloads"):
    if file.endswith(".zip"):
        archives.append(path.join("downloads",content))

for archive in archives:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(archive, "r") as extractor:
                file_stem = Path(path.basename(archive)).stem  # Remove the .zip ending
                unpacked_path = path.join("unpacked", file_stem)
                extractor.extractall(unpacked_path)
```

Is there a better way to find and extract these archives ? Specifically what I am looking for is a better way to search for these zip files instead of looking thought the `listdir` results for a `.zip` ending.

Comment: Use `Path("downloads").glob("*.zip")` [*docs*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob)

Comment: This is a request for code review, not a specific question.

Comment: @DavisHerring maybe I can rephrase it, but the answer above short of answers my intented question. What is the best way to search for these zip files is what I am asking. I added all the code because usually you get roasted for not adding a piece of code along with your question. You cant win in stackoverflow it seems :-)

Comment: There is no better way, your approach is OK. Generally the best way to work with all files of given type is to find them and then work with each of them.